# Not Receiving Email Subscriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I subscribed to a search in careers.stackoverflow.com to receive jobs that match by email.  That was probably 2 or 3 weeks ago and I still have not received any emails even though there have been new jobs posted that match my search request.

Comment: I just set up email subscriptions about a week ago, but have not received any emails. News jobs matching my criteria have definitely been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, we found an issue that was preventing them from going out. You should get one overnight tonight.

Comment: Hello, I have this same issue again.